# In the logarithmic compressor in PCM, which law is used in countries other than the US, Canada and European countries?

Tags: communication, modulation

US and Canada use A-law and Europe use µ-law. I can't seem to find what India and other countries use?

Comment: A-law,adapting ITU-T standards..............g1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few seconds on Google led to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711

Short story: use A-law unless you're in North America or Japan, in which case use µ-law.

Comment: So if you use A-law in North America, your equipment explodes?

Comment: No, you're committing a crime and therefore you can be arrested and locked up for life.

Comment: What, no capital punishment? You people are going soft.